# (Python) Using pop in python to take first element print it and then put it at the bottom of the list

Tags: python, stack

I'm new to python, and I don't know whether it's possible to rotate my stack structure.

My code:

```
class Stack():    
    def __init__(self):
       self.items = []
    def isEmpty(self):
       return self.items == []
    def push(self, item):
       return self.items.append(item)
    def printstack(self):
       for items in reversed(self.items):
           print items
    def pop(self):
       NS=Stack()
       var1=self.items.pop()
       NS.push(var1)    
       NS.push(self)
       self=NS
       return var1

    def size(self):
       return len(self.items)
s=Stack()  
print s.isEmpty()   
print ''  
s.push(4)  
s.push('dog')   
s.push(6)  
s.push('Bob')  
print s.isEmpty()  
print ''  
s.printstack()  
print ''  
print s.pop()  
print ''  
s.printstack()
```

What I am trying to do is customize the pop in a stack to pop and place the pope variable at the end of the stack like the following:

```
True

False

Bob  
6  
dog  
4  

Bob  

6  
dog  
4  
Bob
```

however I'm getting this:

```
True

False

Bob  
6  
dog  
4  

Bob  

6  
dog  
4
```

Help?

Comment: If you do that, it's not a stack any more.

Comment: But a list does not work in my knowledge because u have to rotate all the elements so wouln't a stack that already does that be a better alternative?

Comment: "Better" in what way?  You're just reinventing a ring.  Also, please note that your **Stack** *is* a list -- you're not saving any processing.

Comment: because in a list u would have to rotate each element.  
list=A-B-C-D-E-F  
for loop that does  
list= B-C-D-E-F-A  
Where in a stack u can do pop and it gives u this   
stack=A-B-C-D-E-F   
pop()  
stack=B-C-D-E-F   
stack.append(A)=B-C-D-E-F-A   
which saves more time than the other alternative

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you mean by "rotate each element".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pop` already has a distinctive meaning in data structures; if you change the operation, you'll have communication troubles later.  Instead, name the operation what it is: a `rotate`.

Since the underlying structure is simply a list, you can do this quite easily with slices:

```
items = items[1:] + [items[0]]
```

**Update after comments**

I'm not sure how you would *need* a for loop. Python has many convenient built-in operations and methods to avoid such difficulties. If you're comfortable with learning about more data structures definitely take **Aaron's** suggestion and learn about the **collections** package. There are dictionaries with counter and sorting properties, linked-list types of sequences, and a lot of good support capabilities.

Comment: Thanks Liam still new to this but my professor made it seem impossible cause ud need a for loop and i was confused so i thought a stack would do

Comment: You should add that `collections.deque` has a rotate method

Comment: @AaronHall: yes, deque (Double-Ended QUEue) has a `rotate` method.  It's good for a *real* stretch in learning right now.  I was just keeping it simple.